# NSURLSession and multithreading for downloading multiple files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app on iOS which wants to download data from my server. The data is nothing but simple text files. I would like to download these files in parallel. 
I am getting confused if I should be creating multiple instances of nsurlsession or multiple tasks(NSURLSessionTasks) under one nsurlsession.

I do know nsurlsession APIs are thread safe. And my fundamental confusion here is about following thing:

My NsurlsessionConfiguration is going to be same for the entire time. So, ideally I can use the same instance of NSURLSession for every file. 
But does it make sense to create multiple instance of NSURLSessionTasks in parallel? 
Or better approach is to take make a new NSURLSession for achieving the parallelism.

I am confused to understand if every NSURLSessionTask in the same NSURLSession creates a new end point or it is serialized.

Comment: You can use Alamofire in swift and AFNetworking in Obj-c to maintains API's request. It reduces your most of fatique code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One session with many tasks -- one per request -- will work safely concurrently. Whether the client makes requests across many servers or to a single one makes no difference so long as the concurrency is less than `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` which is part of the session config.

The tasks run in parallel.  (It's actually pretty hard to find a place in the docs where those words appear *explicitly*, but there's pretty good implication [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system?language=objc)).

Notice that session configs have a `delegateQueue`. The rationale is -- because the sessions tasks are run concurrently -- the app level needs to serialize handling of the results, lest two *parallel* tasks step on each other via the delegate.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question. I am curious if NSURLSession serializes NSURLSessionTask or it runs in parallel.

Comment: @agent.smith - NSURLSession runs its tasks in parallel.  I edited to emphasize.